# No debug information upon exception in Django custom field

Tags: django, debugging, exception, error-handling

I created a custom ImageField in Django 1.11, sub-classing the native `ImageFieldFile`:

```
class ImageWithThumbsFieldFile(models.fields.files.ImageFieldFile):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageWithThumbsFieldFile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...

    def save(self, name, content, save=True):
        ...
```

The whole thing works well, however, when I do have any sort of bug within the `save` method, Django doesn't return a proper exception page (despite `DEBUG = True` on dev normal server). I only see a server error 500 - no debug information at all. I do get detailed error info on any other part of the project. Is this normal behavior for errors within a sub-classed field method? Is there a way to get debug info in case of an error?

Thanks!

Comment: `DEBUG=True`? Are you running dev server (manage.py runserver) or something else?

Comment: Yeah, `DEBUG=True` on Django's dev server. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Anything in log files, console output?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Only the error 500 without any details about the code.